# With UK ILR can I get a German visa on arrival?

Tags: visas, germany, schengen-visas, uk-residents

With a UK Indefinite Leave to Remain and a biometric card, can I get a visa on arrival in Germany?

Comment: ILR In the UK has no effect on whether an individual can enter the Schengen area visa-free. If your nationality means you need a visa to enter, having ILR status does not change that requirement.

Answer (score 6):

There are no visas on arrival in Germany (except for the corner case of non-EU family members of EU citizens traveling with them). You will need to apply for your Schengen visa in advance.